# Argumentation fallacies: Impossible to prove the non-existing

Tags: terminology, rhetoric

"It is impossible to prove that something does not exist, it is only possible to prove that sth does exist." - Is there an english term or does there exist a known argumentation fallacy to describe this?

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that you consider a fallacy, that you're seeking a name for? (In particular, I can't tell whether you're saying that it's a fallacy to [try to] prove that something doesn't exist, or whether you're saying that it's a fallacy to claim that it's impossible to prove that something exists. More generally, it might help if you elaborated a bit.)

Comment: [Argument from ignorance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance) or [argument from fallacies](http://www.skepticalraptor.com/skepticalraptorblog.php/logical-fallacies/argument-from-fallacy-logical-fallacies/) ?

Answer (score 2):

The statement that "you can't prove a negative" applies to exclusionary inductive arguments, i.e., arguments that posit the nonexistence of some condition in a sufficiently intractable universe of possibilities.  For example,

> I have never been to Ashtabula, Ohio.

To prove this, I would have to provide evidence that for every moment of my life, I wasn't in Ashtabula.  The inverse argument

> I have been to Ashtabula, Ohio

on the other hand is relatively easy to demonstrate.  I only need evidence of one moment in my life, the one in Ashtabula.  If the universe of the claim is sufficiently limited, then it is possible to prove a negative:

> There are no blond-haired, green-eyed students attending Central High School.

This might require looking at every Central High student, but that's likely possible.

Note that the claim does not apply to deductive arguments.  The claim that

> The square root is not a rational number (i.e, one that's the ratio of integers)

may be demonstrated by a mathematical proof that most students at Central High could understand.  But, of course, it does not rely on examining all rational numbers.

Answer (score 0):

***Proving a negative or [negative proof](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Negative_proof)***:

> A negative proof (known classically as *appeal to ignorance*) is a logical fallacy which takes the structure of:
>
> X is true because there is no proof that X is false.
>   Or
>   You do not know what X is. Therefore we do.
>
> If the only evidence for something's existence is a lack of evidence for it not existing, then the default position is one of mild skepticism and not credulity. This type of negative proof is common in proofs of God's existence or in pseudosciences where it is used as an attempt to shift the burden of proof onto the skeptic rather than the proponent of the idea. The burden of proof is on the individual proposing existence, not the one questioning existence.
>
> A common retort to a negative proof is to reference the existence of the Invisible Pink Unicorn or the Flying Spaghetti Monster as just as valid as the proposed entity of the debate. This is similar to *reductio ad absurdum*, that taking negative proof as legitimate means that one can prove practically anything, regardless of how absurd. [RationalWiki]

The assertion "you can't prove a negative" has been discussed: according to Hales, if you really can't prove a negative, then you can't prove that "you can't prove a negative" is true because the utterance itself is a negative. What is more, all utterances can be expressed as double negatives, which would mean nothing is provable. Actually, you can prove negatives by proving true a situation that is incompatible with the existance of the situation you want to prove false. For more, see [*Thinking Tools: You Can Prove a Negative*, by Steven D. Hales](http://departments.bloomu.edu/philosophy/pages/content/hales/articlepdf/proveanegative.pdf).

Comment: So in some sense, it is begging the question.

Comment: @JasperLocke I don't follow. Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: @JasperLocke No, begging the question is assuming what you're supposed to prove.

Comment: @deadrat begging the question was never a fallacy that was easily understandable to me, but wouldn't: "according to Hales, if you really can't prove a negative, then you can't prove that "you can't prove a negative" is true because the utterance itself is a negative" be considered begging the question?

Comment: @JasperLocke It's a [reductio ad absurdum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum). Hales considers their own assertion as true and demonstrates how a contradiction follows from it, thus proving such assertion false.

Comment: It's not a contradiction when a proposition is true but cannot be proved. The content of Godel's incompleteness theorem is that any consistent axiomatic system that can do arithmetic has infinitely many such propositions.

Comment: @MattSamuel That is true. I considered it an "I know that I know nothing"  paradox: if you can't prove a negative, then you can't prove that you can't prove a negative, and then you can't prove that you can't prove that you can't prove a negative, and so ad infinitum. Asserting that one can't prove a negative is invalid, for one is asserting something one cannot prove by virtue of the assertion itself. Not that it is contradictory, not even necessarily false, just "unassertable."

Comment: @JasperLocke Here's a BTQ argument: *Vegan diets are bad because excluding animal protein from a diet is unhealthy.*  But excluding animal protein from a diet *is* veganism, so this is arguing that vegan diets are bad because vegan diets are unhealthy.  The argument assumes that vegan diets are unhealthy, when that's what the argument needs to demonstrate.  Hales' argument is that "can't prove a negative" is logically self-contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it "burden of proof." The burden of proof is on the person who is purporting that something is true, such as that something exists. If they have not proven their point, it is not the burden of someone else to disprove something which has not been proven to begin with.